# Google Maps setVisible is not a function

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is my `markers[]` array:

```
partnerMarkers = [
        // London
        { lat: 51.515482718, lng: -0.142903122, name: "London", content: "Our home town and international hub." },
// Dubai
        { lat: 25.2644444, lng: 55.3116667, name: "Middle East", content: "Dubai desc" }
];
```

I have this function, looping through the array of markers (triggered by a button elsewhere):

```
function toggle_layer(markers) {
    for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

I get `markers[i].setVisible is not a function` - but then this works fine:

```
function toggle_layer(markers) {
    for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
        console.log(markers[i]);
    }
}
```

Why does setVisible not work in this context?

Comment: What kind of object is markers?

Comment: @NiklasRingdahl it's an array.

Comment: Yeah, but an array of what? I suppose it's supposed to be of Marker, could you provide the code for when the markers object is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [JSFiddle Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/Zg9Fr/)

Seems like your markers are just objects instead of `google.maps.Markers`, and thus it does not have `setVisible()` function within it.  You basically want to convert the data within your Object into a `google.maps.Marker` object.  I created a global array `gooMarker` to hold the Markers.  By clicking on the link below the map, it'll hide the markers.  Here is the way to create Markers and then hide them:

HTML Markup:

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 650px; height: 550px;"></div>
</div>
<div id='hidemark'>Click to hide markers</div>
```

JavaScript + Google Map V3 API:

```
var map;
var gooMarker = [];

var partnerMarkers = [
   {
    lat: 51.515482718,
    lng: -0.142903122,
    name: "London",
    content: "Our home town and international hub."},
    {
    lat: 25.2644444,
    lng: 55.3116667,
    name: "Middle East",
    content: "Dubai desc"}
];

function initialize() {

    var london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, 0);

    var myOptions = {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFF',
        zoom: 2,
        center: london,
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map_canvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

    map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, myOptions);

    for (var i = 0; i < partnerMarkers.length; i++) {
        gooMarker.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(partnerMarkers[i].lat, partnerMarkers[i].lng),
            map: map,
            title: partnerMarkers[i].name
        }));
    }
}

function hideMarkers(){
    for(var i=0; i<gooMarker.length; i++){
        gooMarker[i].setVisible(false);
    }
}

document.getElementById('hidemark').onclick = hideMarkers;

window.onload = initialize;
```

Comment: Thanks - pushing markers into the `gooMarker` array was the key.

Answer (score 2):

kjy112 is on the spot, simplified to plugin direct to your code:

```
partnerMarkers = [
// London
    new google.maps.Marker(
    { position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.515482718, -0.142903122), 
    title: "London - Our home town and international hub." },
// Dubai
    new google.maps.Marker(
    { position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.2644444, 55.3116667), 
    title: "Middle East - Dubai desc" }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the Marker constructor in your code

```
new google.maps.Marker
```